# How to post a calculated data in a form

Tags: html, forms

I've built a form in html to proceed a paiement on my website.

I present the net price and use javascript to calculate the VAT and the gross price according to my client type and location.

Then, both data are populated in divs within my form via the command document.getElementById("").innerHTML

The next thing I want to do is to submit my form to my 1/stripe-2/server via the submit button and the POST method, and charge the gross price through a variable $gross in PHP.

Unfortunatelly, I cannot find any HTML tag to POST from a div object. It looks I can only POST from input, textarea, and select objects.

What would be the workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calculating the gross price again in my PHP file. Guess that's a correct solution...